# Is there a class view in visual studio for f#?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

It is possible to get Visual Studio show me a window, where I can see and search my f# namespaces, classes and methods. I have VisualFSharpPowerTools installed, but the class View of Visual Sudio is empty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I googled it and apparently your question is the first result. Nice!!

According to [this issue on uservoice](https://vfpt.uservoice.com/forums/247560-general/suggestions/6785640-feaure-request-code-navigation-using-class-view) which is linked to from [this issue in Github](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools/issues/879) there isn't a way to do that.

However, and I just tested this: you can use the Navigate shortcut in Visual Studio to jump to the definition of any method (er .. call it a function), or type, or union case. Press `Ctrl + ,` and type away.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that all Files, Namespaces Classes methods appeared here. Fuzzy Search would be a big improvement on `Ctrl + ,`. Can anybody put it in their uservoice or is it already ?

Comment: There used to be a navigation bar in Visual F# Power tools but it got [removed](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools/pull/1364)

Comment: What I found was helpful is the Signature of the F# Class or Module. It is show as a popup when you hover over the class. It is also shown when you `#load "file.fs"`from FSI. Is there a better method to get the signature?